# How do I convert domain.com/foo/bar/baz/ into a string like 'foo bar baz'?

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically I want to be able to grab the ending of an url, and convert it into a string to be used somewhere.

Currently I'm doing this (which is less than optimal):

```
// grab the path, replace all the forward slashes with spaces
local_path = location.pathname.toString().replace(/\//g,' ');

// strip empty spaces from beginning / end of string
local_path.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""));
```

But I think there is probably a better way. Help?

Edit: **Could I confidently get rid of the .toString method there?**

Comment: Your solution seems fine :). In a modern browser you could use local_path.trim() instead of the second one

Comment: What's non-optimal about your method? Looks just fine to me. If you want it all in one call, then chain the final `.replace()` call on to the end of the first `.replace()` call `.replace(/\//g,' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""))`.

Comment: It works yeah. I actually just refined it from something much, much worse (a jQuery each function.. some nasty other stuff). Just wondering if something more efficient / shorter exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this if you want to avoid regular expressions:

```
location.pathname.substring(1).split('/').join(' ')
```

That will get rid of the initial slash, but won't take care of a trailing slash. If you need to deal with those, you can omit `substring` and use `trim` for modern implementations or a regex:

```
location.pathname.split('/').join(' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
```

Comment: right the problem with that is depending on if there is an ending slash (there might be, might not? don't know enough about backend / url rewriting), there will be an extra space at the end of the string stored in the variable. At the end of the day whatever is faster / simpler, but for now my solution would be preferred because it would strip off the spaces no matter what.

Comment: updated to account for space at end, but I'm not sure it's any faster than your way. We can set up a jsPerf and find out... lol ok i just realized you wrote the exact same regex in your question, so maybe this is not helpful

Comment: well except for the toString method... do I need that?

Comment: well, ISTM that [regex is faster than split/join](http://jsperf.com/asdasdsad) for small strings at least. I think your original way is fine. I'm pretty sure location.pathname is always a string, you shouldn't need toString. In general you can do stuff like `''+foo` instead of `foo.toString()` to shorten your code a bit. I don't think there's much of an effect on performance either way.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with what you have? Looks fine to me. That is the easiest way to handle what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex provided by Douglas Crockford on http://www.coderholic.com/javascript-the-good-parts/ and then split the path at the forward-slash.